# Extracting JS from html with preg_match

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I just need to extract the `client_token`value from the [html](https://0bin.net/paste/dAlM1dKjKnn3dAKf#8uauTnspSW+O7MYLbigCJ0aawQ0hCTSvG3i8m2-+jlE) .Here is my attempt thus far

```
preg_match("#var client_token(.*)=(.*)'(.*?)'#is",  $html, $match);
```

Comment: `/var client_token = '(.*?)';/`

Comment: @Mohammad post as an answer so that i can accept

Comment: Please mark one answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the html code is constant you can use bottom code.

```
preg_match("/var client_token = '(.*?)';/",  $html, $match);
```

But if `space` and `qoute` is unknown use this

```
preg_match("/var\s+client_token\s*=\s*[\'|\"](.*?)[\'|\"]\s*;/",  $html, $match);
```

1. `\s+` match one/multiple space
2. `\s*` match none/one/multiple space
3. `['|"]`  match `'` or `"`

Answer (score 1):

Use \s+ instead of .* to avoid matching random stuff:

```
preg_match("#var client_token\s*=\s*'(.*?)'#is",  $html, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most compact and easy to understand:

```
preg_match("/client_token[^\']*\'([^\']*)/",  $html, $match);
```

[Tested and explained here.](https://regex101.com/r/WoWO95/1)